# How to save canvas compressed

Tags: javascript, canvas, upload

So I have this upload script to save my canvas as an image that looks like this.

JS:

```
function save_as() {
var canvas   = document.getElementById("originalCanvas");    
var dataURL  = canvas.toDataURL();
var filename = document.getElementById('SA_filename').value;

if(filename.length < 3) {
    Cerror('filenameshort');
} else if(fileType == 'none') {
    Cerror('filetypenotselected');
}    
else {
    // call upload.php and post the data
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "file-upload/uploadAS.php",
      data: {image: dataURL, filetype: fileType, filename: filename}
    }).done(function( respond ) {
     console.log("Saved filename: "+respond);
    });
}
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"])) {
    if (isset($_POST["filetype"]) && !empty($_POST["filetype"])) {
       if (isset($_POST["filename"]) && !empty($_POST["filename"])) {

        // get the image data
        $data = $_POST['image'];
        $filename = $_POST["filename"] . '.' . $_POST["filetype"];

        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);


        $file = $filename;
        file_put_contents($file, $data);
        echo $file;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The user has the option to save the canvas with different file extensions.
But the problem with this script is that however it does save the canvas to different file extensions, it does not compress them, the file size stays the same no matter what file type you save it as, is there a way to compress these images in the same script? So that they get saved as real PNG, JPG, BMP, Webp or GIFs instead of what it is now?

Comment: since missing file_put_contents($file, $data); implementation, so we cannot infer how the exported canvas will be decoded end saved to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default save format is always PNG or `image/png`. If not specified this will be the save format:

```
var dataURL  = canvas.toDataURL();  // always PNG
```

In order to save as JPEG you need to specify this (quality argument is optional for JPEG and defaults to 0.9 if not specified):

```
var dataURL  = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality); // opt. quality [0, 1]
```

You can try other formats as well but not all browsers supports all formats. If the browser doesn't it will always revert back to PNG which seem to be the case.

You can detect the actual image format used by looking at the returned string (the data-uri). It will contain the mime-type used.